# REDCap- is there a way to remove the suggestions box when entering into a text field

Tags: google-chrome, redcap

Using REDCap in Chrome browser. Currently when users enter data into a text field, the screen will automatically display a list of previously entered values which the user can choose from. However this is not required or desirable in our study. For example, while entering a participant's email address, we do not want the email address of other participants to be displayed.

I have been unable to find any options for this within either REDCap itself or the Browser settings, so would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue https://support.iclasspro.com/hc/en-us/articles/218569268-How-Do-I-Disable-or-Clear-AutoFill-AutoComplete-Information-

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, to solve this you will have to clear your browser's cache